# Laravel 8 ResetsPasswords Trait redirect issue on wrong password

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am using ResetsPasswords trait. In this when I input wrong email I am redirected back with an error but whenever I give wrong password I am redirected to not found page with this url:password/reset. The ResetsPasswords trait is:

```
trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);
    }

    /**
     * Set the user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUserPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200);
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

When the reset is successful the user is logged in to account and is redirected to a specific page. But on wrong password or if password validation is failed I want my self to redirect back to the old page with errors.
My ResetPasswordController is

```
    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    protected $redirectTo = '/play';
```

I have tried to debug following part of the trait but not succeeded.

```
protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
```